# Find and replace text between certain characters with filename

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace

Find and replace text between certain characters with filename, have about 100 files that require this so I'm thinking it needs a occurrence or something.

Original file name: test1.txt

Inside file replace the following two lines with the file name (inside each file the below strings might not be right after each other):

```
location000:/computer/[project]/name/123.php,32,1,2,512,0,,txt
newlocation000:/computer/[project]/name/123.php,32,1,2,512,0,,txt
```

Output in file test1.txt

```
location000:/computer/[project]/name/test1.php,32,1,2,512,0,,txt
newlocation000:/computer/[project]/name/test1.php,32,1,2,512,0,,txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy to achieve task with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript.

```
@echo off
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" (
    echo ERROR: JREPL.BAT missing in directory "%~dp0".
    echo/
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

for %%I in ("C:\Temp\*.txt") do call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^((?:new)?location000:/.+/).*(\.[^.,]+,)" "$1%%~nI$2" /F "%%I" /O -
```

This batch file works only on NTFS drives. It can result in an endless running loop on FAT16, FAT32 or ExFAT drives or skipping some text files. For a working solution independent on file system replace the last command line by:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Temp\*.txt" /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^((?:new)?location000:/.+/).*(\.[^.,]+,)" "$1%%~nI$2" /F "C:\Temp\%%I" /O -
```

The batch file **JREPL.BAT** must be stored in same directory as the batch file with the code above. For that reason the batch file checks first if **JREPL.BAT** really exists in directory of the batch file and if this is not the case, outputs an error message, halts script execution to make it possible for a user to read that error message and then exits. See [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

The command **FOR** searches in specified directory `C:\Temp` for non hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `*.txt` and calls for each found text file the batch file **JREPL.BAT** to replace the file name between **last** `/` and **first** string starting with `.`, having one or more characters not being a dot or a comma with next character being a `,` (= file extension and comma) on lines starting case-sensitive with `location000:/` or `newlocation000:/` by the file name of the current *.txt file without file extension. So a file name in existing file can contain also one or more `.` in file name before file extension.

The solution working also on FAT drives uses command **DIR** to get a **captured** list of *.txt files with just file name and file extension without path and **FOR** processes this file names list line by line, i.e. file name by file name. So the list of *.txt files to process does not change on running **FOR** calling **JREPL.BAT** as it would be the case on using **FOR** directly to find the *.txt files on FAT drives.

NTFS returns a list of directory entries matching a wildcard pattern sorted alphabetically and so the list of *.txt files does not modify during **FOR** iterations in this case. But all FAT file systems return the list of directory entries matching a wildcard pattern according to last modification in directory with last modified file at end of the list. So while **FOR** gets one file name after the other on using `for %%I in ("C:\Temp\*.txt") do` from file system and processes the file with calling `jrepl.bat` which modifies the file, the file list changes on FAT drives and next directory entry returned to **FOR** on its search for `*.txt` is either the file just modified (= endless loop) or another file after skipping a file which should be also modified because of file list changed since last directory access by **FOR**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 being the batch file itself.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`